# How to transform a html table created from code to json object? AngularJS

Tags: html, json, angularjs

I hava a html table create from code in AnguljarJS with a lot of data.

How could i transform this table to JSON? This table is not painted in the HTML file. I've tried everything and I can't transform it. I know there is a method called tableToJSON but that only works with tables that are in the HTML.

```js
let table = document.createElement("table");

table.id = "table";

table.style.display = "none";

let header = table.createTHead();

let row = header.insertRow(0);
row.style.fontWeight = "bold";
row.style.textAlign = "center";
row.style.backgroundColor = "#e2f0ff";
row.style.color = "#04408f";

let cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
cell0.innerHTML = this.$filter("translate")("repository.periodo");

let cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
cell1.innerHTML = this.$filter("translate")("informes.operaciones.areaNegAcc");

let cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
cell2.innerHTML = this.$filter("translate")("repository.dividendos.nomAccionista");

let cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
cell3.innerHTML = this.$filter("translate")("ampliacion.tipope");

let cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
cell4.innerHTML = this.$filter("translate")("informes.operaciones.areaNegPart");

let cell5 = row.insertCell(5);
cell5.innerHTML = this.$filter("translate")("informes.operaciones.nombrePart");

let cell6 = row.insertCell(6);
cell6.innerHTML = this.$filter("translate")("repository.dividendos.porParticipacion");

let cell7 = row.insertCell(7);
cell7.innerHTML = this.$filter("translate")("repository.operaciones.varPorcentaje");

let cell8 = row.insertCell(8);
cell8.innerHTML = this.$filter("translate")("informes.operaciones.saldoEur");


let tBody = document.createElement("tbody");
table.appendChild(tBody);

for (let i = 0; i < vm.listOper.length; i++) {
  var rowTb = tBody.insertRow(i);
  rowTb.style.textAlign = "center";
  rowTb.style.color = "#04408f";

  var celltB1 = rowTb.insertCell(0);
  celltB1.innerHTML = vm.listOper[i].codPeriodoc;

  var celltB2 = rowTb.insertCell(1);
  celltB2.innerHTML = vm.listOper[i].desUnidpetAcc;

  var celltB3 = rowTb.insertCell(2);
  celltB3.innerHTML = vm.listOper[i].codAccion + "-" + vm.listOper[i].desAccion;

  var celltB4 = rowTb.insertCell(3);
  celltB4.innerHTML = vm.listOper[i].desTipoOper;

  var celltB5 = rowTb.insertCell(4);
  celltB5.innerHTML = vm.listOper[i].desUnidpetPart;

  var celltB6 = rowTb.insertCell(5);
  celltB6.innerHTML = vm.listOper[i].codParticip + "-" + vm.listOper[i].desParticip;

  var celltB7 = rowTb.insertCell(6);
  celltB7.innerHTML = vm.listOper[i].porParticipFormat + "%";

  var celltB8 = rowTb.insertCell(7);
  celltB8.innerHTML = vm.listOper[i].varPor ? vm.listOper[i].varPor : "-";

  var celltB9 = rowTb.insertCell(8);
  celltB9.innerHTML = vm.listOper[i].saldoEurFormat;
}

return table;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very un-angular approach, and because you're directly writing to the DOM, you're shooting yourself in the foot when it comes to manipulating or transforming it.

Consider refactoring your table build to be something like this:

```
let tabledata = []
    tabledata.push([
    this.$filter("translate")("repository.periodo"),
    this.$filter("translate")("informes.operaciones.areaNegAcc"),
    this.$filter("translate")("repository.dividendos.nomAccionista"),
    this.$filter("translate")("ampliacion.tipope"),
    this.$filter("translate")("informes.operaciones.areaNegPart"),
    this.$filter("translate")("informes.operaciones.nombrePart"),
    this.$filter("translate")("repository.dividendos.porParticipacion"),
    this.$filter("translate")("repository.operaciones.varPorcentaje"),
    this.$filter("translate")("informes.operaciones.saldoEur)
]);


var elem
for (let i = 0; i < vm.listOper.length; i++) {
    elem = vm.listOper[i]
    tabledata.push([
        elem.codPeriodoc,
        elem.desUnidpetAcc,
        elem.codAccion + "-" + elem.desAccion,
        elem.desTipoOper,
        elem.desUnidpetPart,
        elem.codParticip + "-" + elem.desParticip,
        elem.porParticipFormat + "%",
        elem.varPor ? elem.varPor : "-",
        elem.saldoEurFormat
    ]);
    }

    $scope.tabledata = tabledata;
    // json: JSON.parse(tabledata)


<table>
<tr ng-repeat='x in tabledata track by $index' ng-class='{"headerRow":$index==0}'>
<td ng-repeat='y in x'> {{y}} </td>
</tr></table>
```

Now you've got your data in a tidy little array which you can easily transfer to JSON and a angular friendly table to boot.